# Calculate trading indicator in Python

Tags: python, pandas, trading

I would like to ask for help with the following code:

```
di = (sm - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
c1 = 2 / (di + 1.0)
c2 = 1 - c1
c3 = 3.0 * (cd * cd + cd * cd * cd)
c4 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd * cd + cd + cd * cd * cd)
c5 = 3.0 * cd + 1.0 + cd * cd * cd + 3.0 * cd * cd

asset['i1']=0
asset['i2']=0
asset['i3']=0
asset['i4']=0
asset['i5']=0
asset['i6']=0
asset['i1'] = c1*asset['C']  + c2*(asset['i1'].shift(1))
asset['i2'] = c1*asset['i1'] + c2*(asset['i2'].shift(1))
asset['i3'] = c1*asset['i2'] + c2*(asset['i3'].shift(1))
asset['i4'] = c1*asset['i3'] + c2*(asset['i4'].shift(1))
asset['i5'] = c1*asset['i4'] + c2*(asset['i5'].shift(1))
asset['i6'] = c1*asset['i5'] + c2*(asset['i6'].shift(1))
```

How to change the code, so for every new row calculated to use the previous row calculation? The problem is that Currently it's using the 0 from the previous row.
The target is to calculate Coral Trend Indicator in Python. There is a pandas DataFrame called "asset" containing prices and dates as timestamp.
The Values c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 are the indicator constants. We need to calculate "i1, 'i3'...i6" for the whole dataframe. Every row is calculated from the previous row, somehow maybe there should be used 'apply' function on the dataframe, because currenly it's calculating the whole column(using the previous defined zeros, not the actual value from previous row).
The DataFrame is quete big is there a faster way, because using "for" in the pandas dataframe tooks a lot of time

Thanks

Comment: You are asking us to keep track of a lot of variables.  Can you provide a stripped down minimal example that demonstrates what you are aiming for?  We can provide insight on how to do that and you can draw from it the relevant information and solve your real problem.  We call it [mcve]

Comment: https://www.prorealcode.com/prorealtime-indicators/coral-trend-indicator-thv-coral/

Answer (score 1):

Just make a for loop and hold the previous variable like this:

```
di = (sm - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
c1 = 2 / (di + 1.0)
c2 = 1 - c1
c3 = 3.0 * (cd * cd + cd * cd * cd)
c4 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd * cd + cd + cd * cd * cd)
c5 = 3.0 * cd + 1.0 + cd * cd * cd + 3.0 * cd * cd


asset['i1'] = c1*asset['C']  + c2*(asset['i1'].shift(1))
var = asset['i1']
for index in range(2,7):
    asset['i'+ str(index)] = c1*var + c2*(asset['i'+ str(index)].shift(1))
```

Comment: The DataFrame is quete big is there a faster way, because using for for the pandas dataframe tooks a lot of time

Comment: Yeah I know actually inserting values one by one takes much RAM and processing power.You can first take only the useful row from dataframe as list by ls = df['useful row name'].to_list() method and then after calculating you just replace it with the old one like this df['useful row name'] = ls.